# Epoll on regular files

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, epoll

Can `epoll` (on Linux) be somehow useful for regular files? I know it's primarily used with sockets but just wonder.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not really. `epoll` only makes sense for file descriptors which would normally exhibit blocking behavior on read/write, like pipes and sockets. Normal file descriptors will always either return a result or end-of-file more or less immediately, so `epoll` wouldn't do anything useful for them.

Comment: That is, it functions, though meaninglessly: "The poll() function shall support regular files... Regular files shall always poll TRUE for reading and writing." http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/poll.html  The epoll(4) man page says: "when used as a Level Triggered interface, epoll is by all means a faster poll(2), and can be used wherever the latter is used since it shares the same semantics." Therefore, as duskwuff says, it won't do anything useful.

Comment: Which is so silly and wrong.  The kernel could hang up for a lot of reasons, from disk spin up (if asleep), down to network lag from a network mounted share/drive.  Any kind of device interaction could cause an IO hang. select/epoll/poll/kqueue should be made to work with any file descriptor as well as any file description should allow non blocking.

Comment: @Rahly That isn't possible. The kernel doesn't know ahead of time whether a write to a file will block -- unlike sockets or pipes, buffers for filesystem writes are not dedicated to a single FD, so there's no way to guarantee they will be available for a specific process.

Comment: @duskwuff sure it can, it just chooses not to due to specific restraints.  For example, the kernel knows what the buffers contains.  Epoll in general isn't a guarantee of anything.  Just more than likely.  In theory anyway, readahead, could "ask" the system for specific data, and put a EPOLLIN/EPOLLERR signal into the epoll queue.  Also, just because it DOESN'T do it, doesn't mean it still isn't silly and/or wrong.  How the implementation is done is irrelevant to how it should function.

Comment: In [this repo it is said](https://github.com/littledan/linux-aio/issues/2) that _"Linux has limited support for using epoll as a mechanism for asynchronous I/O [...] if the file is opened as O_NONBLOCK, then a read will return EAGAIN until the relevant part is in memory"_, which contradicts this answer. But in a simple test I couldn't confirm that. Who's right?

Comment: @nh2 I'd say that document is wrong. https://lwn.net/Articles/612483/ has some background -- in particular, `open(…, O_NONBLOCK)` is currently interpreted as only making **opening the file** nonblocking, not subsequent I/O operations.

Comment: Contra the last comment, `man 2 open` says WRT O_NONBOCK: *"Neither the open() **nor any subsequent I/O operations** on the file descriptor  which is returned will cause the calling process to wait."*  However, it also notes (with a few qualifications that *"this  flag has no effect for regular files"*.

Answer (score 23):

I think, it will fail at epoll_ctl with  [EPERM](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html):

> ```
>    EPERM  The target file fd does not support epoll.
> ```

if the file has no `poll()` interface.

The actual code is http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1/fs/eventpoll.c#L1373

```
1373    /* The target file descriptor must support poll */
1374        error = -EPERM;
1375        if (!tfile->f_op || !tfile->f_op->poll)
1376                goto error_tgt_fput;
1377
```