# Python cdll inotify watch descriptor fails only in async task

Tags: python, linux, python-asyncio, epoll, inotify

I'm trying to run a filesystem watcher in an async task which worked well, but when I tried to move the watch descriptor creation into the task it stopped working. Changing where that line was called is the only change that causes the issue. I cannot see anything in the asyncio docs that indicate this shouldn't be possible.

I've made the smallest reproducible example I can below. It doesn't seem to matter where the file descriptor is initialised, only where the watch is called.

```py
import asyncio, ctypes, ctypes.util, io, logging, os

# https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html
class _INotifyEvent(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("wd", ctypes.c_int),
        ("mask", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("cookie", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("len", ctypes.c_uint32),
        # ("name", char[])
    ]

_libc = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library("c"), use_errno=True)
_libc.inotify_init1.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int,)
_libc.inotify_add_watch.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_uint)
EVENT_SIZE = ctypes.sizeof(_INotifyEvent) + 1

class FilesystemMonitor:
    def __init__(self, path: str, delayed=False):
        self._file_descriptor = _libc.inotify_init1(os.O_CLOEXEC)
        self._path = path
        self._wd = None
        if not delayed:
            self.add_watch()

    def add_watch(self):
        self._wd = _libc.inotify_add_watch(self._file_descriptor, bytes(self._path, "utf-8"), 8)
        print("WD =", self._wd)

    def get(self):
        buffer = io.BytesIO(os.read(self._file_descriptor, EVENT_SIZE))
        event_buffer = buffer.read(EVENT_SIZE)
        event = _INotifyEvent.from_buffer_copy(event_buffer)
        return self._path if event.wd == self._wd else "unknown"

    async def start(self, queue: asyncio.Queue):
        ioloop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

        if self._wd is None:
            self.add_watch()

        def _add_to_queue():
            queue.put_nowait(self.get())

        ioloop.add_reader(self._file_descriptor, _add_to_queue)

async def run_monitor(monitor):
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    asyncio.gather(monitor.start(queue))
    while True:
        print("!!! EVENT:", await queue.get())

async def run(delayed):
    print("Start, delayed =", delayed)
    path = "/tmp/file.txt"
    monitor = FilesystemMonitor(path, delayed=delayed)
    asyncio.create_task(run_monitor(monitor))

    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write("content")

    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # yield so run_monitor reads from queue
    print("End")

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
for val in (True, False):
    asyncio.run(run(val))
```

The output of which is

```
$ touch /tmp/file.txt && PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 python3.11 temp.py 
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
Start, delayed = True
WD = 1
End
DEBUG:asyncio:Close <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=True>
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
Start, delayed = False
WD = 1
!!! EVENT: /tmp/file.txt
End
DEBUG:asyncio:Close <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=True>
```

Adding the following to the end of `add_watch` shows inotify has created a watch descriptor in both cases.

```py
        with open(f"/proc/{os.getpid()}/fdinfo/{self._file_descriptor}") as f:
            print(f.read())
```

Reading [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351999/what-file-descriptor-object-does-python-asyncios-loop-add-reader-expect) and a [question linked to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645721/why-does-select-select-work-with-disk-files-but-not-epoll), it implies that async's usage of epoll prevents it from working. However, the same watch *does* work in async if it's created outside of the async loop. Just to check, I tried changing the async event loop policy using the following, and trying all other `Selector` classes available, but nothing changed the outcome.

```py
import selectors

class MyPolicy(asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy):
    def new_event_loop(self):
        selector = selectors.SelectSelector()
        return asyncio.SelectorEventLoop(selector)

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(MyPolicy())
```

Attempting to PDB through the async behaviour didn't help identify anything. I fear I'm simply misunderstanding something fundamental about the behaviour of async here. Can anyone explain why the async task works for a watch created outside of async but fails for a watch created within it? And is there a way to make it work?